# Passing additional data to Generic RenderFragment in Blazor component

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, generics, blazor

I have a simple Blazor component which iterates over a Generic List :

```
@typeparam TItem;

 @foreach (var item in List)
        {
            @ElementTemplate(item); // What code should be here to pass i to the ElementTemplate????
            i++;
        }

@code {
    int i = 0;


    [Parameter] public List<TItem> List { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment<TItem> ElementTemplate { get; set; }
  }
```

I have another simple component which will get an item and an index to render data(Employee):

```
<div> @Index . @Person.Name </div>

@code{
    [Parameter] public Person { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public int Index { get; set; }

}
```

And in my main page I have the following:

```
<GenericList List="employees">
    <ElementTemplate>
        <Employee Person="context" Index="?"></Employee>
    </ElementTemplate>
</GenericList>
```

As you can see Employee component needs an Index parameter, how can I pass the Index from the GenericList component?
In this example the variable 'i' should be passed to ElementTemplate as well as the Generic TItem object itself.

Comment: You can't - you explicitly specified that `ElementTemplate` accepts a single data item. If you want that to contain multiple things you could have it inherit from a base class or implement an interface and use that as a generic constraint. Or, make the data item `dynamic`, losing the benefits of generics

Comment: You can set up a dictionary to map your model type to a component for rendering. Use that to pass over the list. I extended ```ComponentBase``` for the mapped components, ```ViewComponentBase<TModel> : ComponentBase```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I find the quick/simple approach is to use a tuple as the RenderFragment context:

```
@foreach (var item in List)
{
  @ElementTemplate((item,i));
  i++;
}

@code {
  int i=0;
  [Parameter] public List<TItem> List { get; set; }
  [Parameter] public RenderFragment<(TItem item, int index)> ElementTemplate { get; set; }
}
```

Then your markup becomes:

```html
<GenericList List="employees">
    <ElementTemplate>
        <Employee @key=@context.index Person=@context.item Index=@context.index></Employee>
    </ElementTemplate>
</GenericList>
```

If you prefer, you could use a utility class in the GenericList instead of a tuple.

Comment: I like the tuple but wouldn't `@key=context`  or at least `@key=context.item` be better?  index is the least coupled to the Employee content.  Suppose you delete an item.

Comment: Well, I didn't want to get into the whole issue of how those index ints are not really reliably coupled to the data, and just wanted to sneak that `@key` in there - using the quickest type available. But you could be right - it all depends on the actual real-world content.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a complex class for your Context

In the GenericList.razon, define a class:

```cs
public class ListContext
{
    public TItem Item {get; set;}
    public int Index {get; set;}
}
```

and use this class as a context type for your template:

```cs
[Parameter] 
public RenderFragment<ListContext> ElementTemplate { get; set; }
```

then when you call this template, you can just create a new class and set the correct parameters:

```cs
@foreach (var item in List)
{
    @ElementTemplate(new ListContext{Item = item, Index = i});
    i++;
}
```

here is a working example of this: https://blazorrepl.com/repl/cuvakzPF21sXSZGK54

Comment: @Thank you but this is not the way that I wanted to do that.

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly? Maybe passing the index from GenericList component using Cascading value will work?